# I'm getting an undefined method error when running tests on rails 4 with guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, guard, rake-test

I was happily working along in Hartl's tut (exactly here https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout#code-contact_page_test) when I started getting this error in guard and have not been able to find anything to do with any methods or method calls regarding '[]', any help greatly appreciated. https://github.com/mgmacri/sample-app

```
02:23:12 - INFO - Running:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run `rake db:migrate` to create it, then try again. If you do not intend to use a database, you should instead alter /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/config/application.rb to limit the frameworks that will be loaded.
Started

ERROR["test_should_get_contact", StaticPagesControllerTest, 5.435833117]
 test_should_get_contact#StaticPagesControllerTest (5.44s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
            app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___423443063036763089_70222525057280'
            test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:24:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
        app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___423443063036763089_70222525057280'
        test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:24:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

ERROR["test_should_get_help", StaticPagesControllerTest, 10.237566481]
 test_should_get_help#StaticPagesControllerTest (10.24s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
            app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___423443063036763089_70222525057280'
            test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
        app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___423443063036763089_70222525057280'
        test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

ERROR["test_should_get_about", StaticPagesControllerTest, 14.55194709]
 test_should_get_about#StaticPagesControllerTest (14.55s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
            app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___423443063036763089_70222525057280'
            test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:18:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
        app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___423443063036763089_70222525057280'
        test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:18:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

ERROR["test_should_get_home", StaticPagesControllerTest, 19.535717523]
 test_should_get_home#StaticPagesControllerTest (19.54s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
            app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___423443063036763089_70222525057280'
            test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
        app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___423443063036763089_70222525057280'
        test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

  4/4: [===================================] 100% Time: 00:00:19, Time: 00:00:19

Finished in 19.54385s
4 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 4 errors, 0 skips

==================================================================
```

*app/views/layouts/application.html.erb*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                           "data-turbolinks-track" =>   true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

==========================================================
*app/helpers/application_helper.rb*

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title = '')
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      "#{page_title} | #{base_title}"
    end
  end
end
```

===========================================================================
test/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test "should get home" do
    get :home
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get :help
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get :about
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get contact" do
    get :contact
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end
end
```

====================

https://github.com/mgmacri/sample-app

Comment: Did you try migrating the database as suggested (`rake db:migrate`)? If so, and you still get this error, do you see `db/schema.rb`?

Comment: I hadn't tried it up until now (on a new branch), because the two seem entirely unrelated, and nowhere in the chapter did we touch a database/model yet. The only thing we did in this chapter was add some partials to layouts/application.html.erb and then wrote a test for adding the page contact. I added it like normal, defined the method in the controller and ended it. Added the routes in config/routes.rb. Finally added a view with some html as per the instruction in chapter 5.

Comment: Where is this full title method which u have written in line no 5 in application.html.erb

Comment: Provided in the edit @Hemali

Comment: can we take a look at your `static_pages_controller_test.rb`? Thanks!

Comment: Provided in the last edit for you, @tmehta2442

Comment: ok... lets try taking a look at the `app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb` ... BTW- did you happen to make a repo for this like on GitHub? If so (and if not, please do :)  ) send over the link and that way we can take a look at the whole app.

Comment: Yeah sure thing, here you go @tmehta2442 https://github.com/mgmacri/sample-app

Comment: Cloned from here: https://github.com/albatross7817/hartl_ch5_tut

ran diff over the whole mess and stick for stick same code in all the spots rspec was testing. I'm just going to pretend I never saw the failures and quietly back out of the old directory. cd ..

Answer (score 0):

The book missed a line.
Add gem 'guard' on your Gemfile on this part

`group :development do
  gem 'guard' # NOTE: this is necessary in newer versions
  gem 'guard-minitest'
end`

source: [here](https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest#install)